# Center a UILabel of a UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am currently trying to make a simple pop up, here I have a button, once it gets tapped.

It should show a simple view above it, I achieved the `blue background`, but I am not being able to add a label to it, and center the `label` to the `blue popup`

```
let width = (sender as! UIButton).frame.width
let y = (sender as! UIButton).frame.origin.y
let x = (sender as! UIButton).frame.origin.x

myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y - 30, width:width, height: 30))
myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

let label = UILabel()
label.text = (sender as! UIButton).titleLabel?.text
label.font = UIFont(name:"avenirNext-Meduim",size:20)
label.center = self.myView.center
myview.addSubview(label)
self.view.addSubview(myView)

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, delay: 0.1, options: [], animations: {

    self.myView.alpha = 0.0

}) { (finished: Bool) in

    self.myView.isHidden = true
}
```

Comment: *any* reason you are trying to do that in code instead of the interface builder?

Comment: @luk2302, do i have to include reasons on my stackoverflow post? " i am new to swift " sorry!

Comment: Try to set your label frame, CGRect(origin: .zero, size: yourLabelSize)

Comment: please write that as an answer, so i can give the right checkmark and others would benefit your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your label frame:

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: yourLabelSize))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer,  `label.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: myView.frame.height/2, y:myView.frame.width/2), size: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)) ` but it does not work, it adds it at the end of the view, i am new to swift, your guiding are appreciated

Comment: You are welcome, after you have set the frame you can set label.center = myView.center, or if you want to add the constraints you have to set them after myView.addSubview(label)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
label.center = self.myView.center
```

try

```
label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

after

```
myview.addSubview(label)
self.view.addSubview(myView)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer,, `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x600000460dc0 "UILabel:0x7f9b8dd05840'Q'.centerX"> and <NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x60000027d900 "UIView:0x7f9b8dc03dc0.centerX"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'`, it does not work

Comment: add the label as a subview first! If you want your label right in the center of your view, add the same constraint for your y-axis/anchor!

Comment: Edited my answer for clarification

Comment: Are you sure you are adding both: the label and the myView to your viewcontroller's view first before adding this code? The error should not occur then.

Comment: @Bruno it’s probably be better to constrain on the top, leading, trailing and bottom anchors because of the label string becomes to long, it can look strange as well as numberOfLines won’t take effect without having a defined leading and trailing anchor

Answer (score 0):

My solution

```
    let codedLabel:UILabel = UILabel()
    codedLabel.frame = CGRect(x: myView.center.x, y: myView.center.y, width: 51, height: 30)
    codedLabel.textAlignment = .center
    codedLabel.text = "q"
    codedLabel.numberOfLines = 1
    codedLabel.textColor=UIColor.red
    codedLabel.font=UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)
    codedLabel.backgroundColor=UIColor.lightGray

    self.myView.addSubview(codedLabel)
    codedLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    codedLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    codedLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    codedLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: codedLabel.superview!.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    codedLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: codedLabel.superview!.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

let headerView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 50))
let label = UILabel()
label.frame = CGRect.init(x: headerView.center.x-60, y:headerView.center.y-15, width: 120, height: 30)
label.textAlignment = .center
label.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1290470958, green: 0.2743584514, blue: 0.6418049335, alpha: 1)
label.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Bold", size: 15)
label.text = "11-12-2020"
headerView.addSubview(label)
headerView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9967060685, green: 0.9998621345, blue: 0.9997505546, alpha: 1)